# Set Enum values using reflection in Protocol buffers

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, protocol-buffers

I have an Enum `Update update` in  a .proto file . I want to store it using *reflections* in a message.

```
refl->SetEnum (msg, fd , ???   );
```

???? - should be EnumValueDescriptor * (I do not know how to get it)

How can I do this?

I have tried `message_desc->FindEnumTypeByName(s)->FindValueByNumber(update)` for many different possibilities of s like:

```
UpdateType
UpdateType::CONFIRM
CONFIRM
....
....
```

Comment: What do you know about the value you wish to set? See e.g. `Descriptor::FindEnumValueByName` or `EnumDescriptor::FindValueByName`, `FindValueByNumber` et al

Comment: I do know how to get Descriptor::FindEnumValueByName. I just have a simple c++ enum value ``update`` and I want to set it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean you "have" it? Have in what form? What's stopping you from calling `Descriptor::FindEnumValueByName` (which returns `EnumValueDescriptor*`), then passing its return value along to `SetEnum`? I don't quite grasp the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, what should be its argument Descriptor::FindEnumValueByName(????), which std::string ?

Comment: The name of the enum value, naturally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need in the third argument is EnumValueDescriptor*.

Also as you can see you have passed FieldDescriptor in the second argument. So just use FieldDesciptor::enum_type() to get EnumDescriptor* and then use EnumDescriptor::Value() to get EnumValueDescriptor.